# Crossy road CRAB character

Tags: crossy-road

I just unlocked a crab on crossy road. I can not find anyone else who has unlocked this character and I'm not sure how I unlocked it? Has anyone else unlocked this character or heard of it? Also does anyone know how to unlock the disco elephant?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? For example, "has anyone else done this" would be off-topic for this site, but "how did I do this" would be on-topic.

Comment: a disco elephant should be a character u get from the slot and for crab just swipe left to right in the sand with a australian character

Answer (score 2):

You have to constantly swipe side to side for as long as you can... How I got it was I was using an Australian animal like the echidna and was just just swiping side to side until the eagle killed me...it could probably be any character but just to be sure use one of the new Australian characters and swipe in the sandy/dirt areas.

Comment: Got it by traversing quickly from one side of the level to the other a few times.  This answer should be picked!

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer (at least according to my kid!)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you got it out of the machine with 100 coins, or it was one of the three random limited time ones you can choose sometimes after a level (and then play with for a few runs, with the option to buy with real money if you don't want to wait and let it happen by chance from the machine).

Comment: It showed up after I played with forget me not and collected about 15 puzzle pieces. It just sort of showed a box that said new and had the crab in it and now the crab shows up to the left of the piggy bank in character selection.